# Zookeeper client exception when executing any command in client

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cassandra, hbase, apache-zookeeper

This is my configuration file:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=20
syncLimit=5
dataDir=./store/data
clientPort=2181

server.1=A:3181:4181
server.2=B:3181:4181
server.3=C:3181:4181
server.4=D:3181:4181
server.5=E:3181:4181
```

After this, I started all of the servers. Then I started client in one of those nodes. It shows connected but as soon as I enter any command it threw exception and stopped.

```
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
2012-11-08 22:35:01,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1083] - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 20000ms for sessionid 0x13ae22116e50001, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1463)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1491)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:725)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:593)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:365)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:323)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:282)
```

- Required ports are open (2181, 3181, 4181)
- myid is being placed and has correct id corresponding to IP address
- Java version: java version "1.7.0_09" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)

Any idea whats going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which component are you getting this exception ?

Comment: thanks @Pierre-LucBertrand for your response, I have figured it out. Had some bad configuration in another file. thanks again

Comment: @tanzir whow could you solve it?

Comment: @kamaci it's been a while and I almost forgot what I did to fix it (may be it was related to my firewall settings). But yesterday I have installed a fresh copy of Zookeeper server and didn't face any issue. Which Java version you are using?

Comment: Ok I have solved that problem too. It was because of a misconfiguration of Zookeeper, thanks.